# URLError : How to get the response body when a exception is raised

Tags: python, exception, postman, microservices, http-error

I am using **URLError** to handle any URL exceptions.
Whenever there is an HTTP error, the exception object only contains the response header. But I need the json body to debug more.

This is the result I get when I use postman

```
{
  "message": "Storage is full",
  "success": false
}
```

This is the exception handling in python

```
except URLError, e:
    print(e)
```

This is the output

```
HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST
```

Is there a way to retrieve the message ("Storage is full") as well in python using **URLError**?

Comment: At first blush I'd say there is some attribute you can dot into. `print(e.reason)` Try this link: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: I tried that. It just prints " BAD REQUEST ".

Comment: Now that I think about it, the 'message' and 'success' keys are probably part of the response. Perhaps the body? If you set the response to some variable you should be able to dig around in there. Also the response should have an info() method. "this returns a dictionary-like object that describes the page fetched, particularly the headers sent by the server. It is currently an http.client.HTTPMessage instance." might be useful. Also see https://docs.python.org/2.2/lib/httpresponse-objects.html, looks like read() give you access to the HTTP response body.